# Varnish "FetchError no backend connection" error

Tags: linux, nginx, varnish

Varnishlog:

```
    0 CLI          - Rd ping
    0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1340829925 1.0
   12 SessionOpen  c 79.124.74.11 3063 :80
   12 SessionClose c EOF
   12 StatSess     c 79.124.74.11 3063 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 CLI          - Rd ping
    0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1340829928 1.0
    0 CLI          - Rd ping
    0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1340829931 1.0
   12 SessionOpen  c 108.62.115.226 46211 :80
   12 ReqStart     c 108.62.115.226 46211 467185881
   12 RxRequest    c GET
   12 RxURL        c /
   12 RxProtocol   c HTTP/1.0
   12 RxHeader     c User-Agent: Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com/)
   12 RxHeader     c Host: www.mysite.com
   12 VCL_call     c recv lookup
   12 VCL_call     c hash
   12 Hash         c /
   12 Hash         c www.mysite.com
   12 VCL_return   c hash
   12 VCL_call     c miss fetch
   12 FetchError   c no backend connection
   12 VCL_call     c error deliver
   12 VCL_call     c deliver deliver
   12 TxProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
   12 TxStatus     c 503
   12 TxResponse   c Service Unavailable
   12 TxHeader     c Server: Varnish
   12 TxHeader     c Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   12 TxHeader     c Retry-After: 5
   12 TxHeader     c Content-Length: 418
   12 TxHeader     c Accept-Ranges: bytes
   12 TxHeader     c Date: Wed, 27 Jun 2012 20:45:31 GMT
   12 TxHeader     c X-Varnish: 467185881
   12 TxHeader     c Age: 1
   12 TxHeader     c Via: 1.1 varnish
   12 TxHeader     c Connection: close
   12 Length       c 418
   12 ReqEnd       c 467185881 1340829931.192433119 1340829931.891024113 0.000051022 0.698516846 0.000074035
   12 SessionClose c error
   12 StatSess     c 108.62.115.226 46211 1 1 1 0 0 0 256 418
    0 CLI          - Rd ping
    0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1340829934 1.0
    0 CLI          - Rd ping
    0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1340829937 1.0
```

---

```
netstat -tlnp
 Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3086/nginx      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1915/varnishd   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1279/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3195/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:6082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1914/varnishd   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1317/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1192/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3195/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3072/memcached  
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      3086/nginx      
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1915/varnishd   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1279/sshd
```

---

/etc/nginx/site-enabled/default

```
server {
    listen   8080; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    listen   [::]:8080 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to index.html
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /doc {
        root /usr/share;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.2;
        deny all;
    }

    location /images {
        root /usr/share;
        autoindex off;
    }

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    #}

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.2:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

---

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www.mysite.com.vhost

```
server {
       listen 8080;
       server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com.net;
       root /var/www/www.mysite.com/web;
       if ($http_host != "www.mysite.com") {
                 rewrite ^ http://www.mysite.com$request_uri permanent;
       }
       index index.php index.html;
       location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
       }
       location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
       }
       # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
       location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
       }
       location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
       }
       # Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
       rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
       location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
       }
       location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.2:9000;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       }

include /var/www/www.mysite.com/web/nginx.conf;
       location ~ /nginx.conf {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
       }

}
```

---

```
/etc/varnish/default.vcl

# This is a basic VCL configuration file for varnish.  See the vcl(7)
# man page for details on VCL syntax and semantics.
# 
# Default backend definition.  Set this to point to your content
# server.
# 
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.2";
    .port = "8080";
    # .connect_timeout = 600s;
    #.first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    # .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
    # .max_connections = 800;
```

---

Note: uncommenting the last four options at default.vcl made no difference.

---

cat /etc/default/varnish

```
# Configuration file for varnish
#
# /etc/init.d/varnish expects the variables $DAEMON_OPTS, $NFILES and $MEMLOCK
# to be set from this shell script fragment.
#

# Should we start varnishd at boot?  Set to "yes" to enable.
START=yes

# Maximum number of open files (for ulimit -n)
NFILES=131072

# Maximum locked memory size (for ulimit -l)
# Used for locking the shared memory log in memory.  If you increase log size,
# you need to increase this number as well
MEMLOCK=82000

# Default varnish instance name is the local nodename.  Can be overridden with
# the -n switch, to have more instances on a single server.
INSTANCE=$(uname -n)

# This file contains 4 alternatives, please use only one.

## Alternative 1, Minimal configuration, no VCL
#
# Listen on port 6081, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to
# content server on localhost:8080.  Use a 1GB fixed-size cache file.
#
# DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
#              -T localhost:6082 \
#        -b localhost:8080 \
#        -u varnish -g varnish \
#            -S /etc/varnish/secret \
#        -s file,/var/lib/varnish/$INSTANCE/varnish_storage.bin,1G"


## Alternative 2, Configuration with VCL
#
# Listen on port 6081, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to
# one content server selected by the vcl file, based on the request.  Use a 1GB
# fixed-size cache file.
#
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T 127.0.0.2:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s file,/var/lib/varnish/$INSTANCE/varnish_storage.bin,1G"
```

If you need any other info let me know. I am all out of clue as to whats the problem.

---

curl header gives me this:

```
curl -v -I -H "Testing: Test header so you see this works" http://www.mysite.com:8080
* About to connect() to www.mysite.com port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 176.31.158.78... connected
* Connected to www.mysite.com (176.31.158.78) port 8080 (#0)
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: www.mysite.com:8080
> Accept: */*
> Testing: Test header so you see this works
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.0.5
Server: nginx/1.0.5
< Date: Thu, 28 Jun 2012 11:01:23 GMT
Date: Thu, 28 Jun 2012 11:01:23 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 184
Content-Length: 184
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://www.mysite.com/
Location: http://www.mysite.com/

< 
* Connection #0 to host www.mysite.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: Try enabling backend polling. https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/BackendPolling 

Does nginx return your content if you hit it directly on port 8080 with curl or wget?

Comment: The last time [I saw this](http://www.thatsgeeky.com/2012/03/varnish-nothing-but-503s/), the problem was SELinux. As a test, try to turn it off: `echo 0 >/selinux/enforce`. If you confirm that it is the problem, you can set an exception with `audit2allow`.

Comment: There are something on nginx error_log ? maybe a 503 error ? and in your mysite.com.vhost try to remove lines 5, 6 and 7 and then try again to access.

Comment: Does it work with malloc instead of file? You might also need the closing } in your vcl file.

Comment: I posted an answer even if your post is very old, because I had the same error and searched a while before I realized this was caused by non www to www redirections

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when trying to test Varnish locally with different backends. Using `127.0.0.1:8080` worked fine but changing the port to `8081` gave me a 503, even though that backend worked perfectly for me outside Varnish.

The problem was caused by SELinux not allowing the connection. I found that out by tailing the audit log and provoking the 503 from Varnish:

`$ sudo tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log
type=AVC msg=audit(1539253067.438:1379): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=10154 comm="varnishd" dest=8081 scontext=system_u:system_r:varnishd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:transproxy_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket`

To see ports allowed by SELinux from Varnish you can use this command:

`$ sudo semanage port -l | grep http_cache_port_t
http_cache_port_t              tcp      8080, 8118, 8123, 10001-10010`

To fix the issue you can either use another port, e.g. `8118` or ask SELinux to allow connections to `8081` from Varnish.

The command to add the port is - the `-a` flag is to add the port:

`semanage port -a -t http_cache_port_t -p tcp 8081`

If you get a message telling you that the port is already defined then you need to modify rather than add the port:

`ValueError: Port tcp/8081 already defined`

The command swaps the `-a` flag for `-m` - 'modify':

`semanage port -m -t http_cache_port_t -p tcp 8081`

Answer (score 0):

You should try logging in with the varnish user and test the connection into the Nginx backend (127.0.0.2:8080) with curl or wget to make sure it is working as expected.

As cyberx86 said on the comments, it can be a problem SELinux (or any other security modules as apparmor, grsec, etc) not allowing the connection between the services and you should also check the audit logs to make sure it's not happening in your server.

If your backend is not working correctly (errors on Nginx execution) you will have this kind of problems, try to access the backend directly and check the logs to make sure everything is running as expected (Pax told you that on the comments as well).

Answer (score 0):

Varnish is receiving data upfront and should listen to port 80. Data from Varnish is proxy to Nginx which listens to port 8080.

**Nginx Config**

```
server {
    listen 800;
    server_name www.example.com
}
```

**Varnish Config** - sudo nano /etc/default/varnish

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \               #note on port 80 here
         -T localhost:6082 \
         -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
         -S /etc/varnish/secret \
         -s malloc,256m"
```

Then here's the Varnish proxy config to port 8080 (Nginx) - sudo nano /etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I 've had the same error in a multiple sites configuration, and **non www to www domains redirection was the problem**. This is how I configured it (relevant parts).

In your `.vcl`, into `sub vcl_recv`

```
vcl 4.0;

sub vcl_recv {
    #THIS IS THE IMPORTANT POINT
    #redirect non www to www domains ip no subdomain defined
    if (req.http.host ~ "^([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)\.([a-zA-Z]+)$") {
       return (synth (750, ""));
    }

    # Normalize the header, remove the port
    set req.http.host = regsub(req.http.host, ":[0-9]+", "");

    #OFTEN SHIPS WITH THIS OTHER ONE, COMMENT IT OTHERWISE IT WILL FAIL
    #set req.http.Host = regsub(req.http.Host, "^www\.", "");

    # For the sake of example, a couple of custom backends, 
    # note www is specified in the req.http.host
    if (req.http.host ~ "foo.example.tld") {
         set req.backend_hint = example;
    }
     elseif (req.http.host ~ "www.other.com") {
         set req.backend_hint = other;
    }
```

Then in `sub vcl_synth`, add this :

```
sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 750) {
        #redirect non www to www
        set resp.status = 301;
        set resp.http.Location = "http://www." + req.http.host + req.url;
        return(deliver);
    }
```

So that **redirection will be handled by Varnish before requesting backend**, avoiding loops, or no backend connection...

Last, in your site vhost, it is not necessary anymore to have two server blocks, you can comment or remove the non www one

```
#server {
#        listen 1.2.3.4:8080;
#        server_name example.tld;
#        return 301 http://www.example.tld;
#}

server {
        listen 1.2.3.4:8080;
        server_name www.example.tld;
```